# python program to dispaly user input from -N to N

Tags: python-2.7

Iam new in python programming.I have a following question.
How to display a user input number from -n to n.
Suppose if user enters 2 and it should display -2,-1,0,1,2

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score -2):

Do this :

```
def f():
    n = input("Value n = ?")
    for i in range(-n,n+1):
        print i
```

and then call your function